# Sending data from one activity to another causes app to crash in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I am very new to Android Studio and am having some issues sending data received from the device via Bluetooth to a new activity.

I do have a foreground service class but am not sure if from there is where I send that data or not. In the function below I am receiving the data and creating an intent to send it to the other activity.

Basically, I am receiving the data sent continuously for now and it needs to be redirected to another activity.

```
@Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        //deviceList.setText("Data");
        byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("BLE", "receive value ----------------------------");
                output.append("BLE receive value ----------------------------\n");
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.data)).append(output);
                }
        });
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    Log.w("BLE", "character_value = " + value[i]);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity4.this, MainActivity5.class);
                    intent2.putExtra("inputExtra", value[i]);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

When the process reaches the part where the data is to be sent to new activity the app crashes. Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Here is the Logcat I get when the app crashes

```
2021-03-29 21:20:50.554 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah W/BLE: character_value = 0
2021-03-29 21:20:50.594 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah W/BLE: character_value = 0
2021-03-29 21:20:50.630 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah W/BLE: character_value = -128
2021-03-29 21:20:50.669 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@d16ea24
2021-03-29 21:20:50.698 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-03-29 21:20:50.703 16879-16879/com.example.Pillwoah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.Pillwoah, PID: 16879
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Pillwoah/com.example.Pillwoah.MainActivity5}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.content.Intent.getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.content.Intent.getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.Pillwoah.MainActivity5.<init>(MainActivity5.java:119)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3183)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: can you share the error from logcat please ?

Comment: I edited the post with the logcat

Comment: are you sure this is the error ?

Comment: There are more errors in logcat prior to this logcat screen but they disappear

Comment: I edited post with logcat I got when I ran it again

Comment: On your MainActiviy5 dont use getByteArrayExtra instead  use intent.getByteExtra

Comment: from your MainActivity4 you sent a byte extra and you try to recive a ByteArray in your MainActivity5

Comment: I tried this and I still get an error. Intent intent = getIntent();           byte[] data = intent.getByteExtra("inputExtra"); Is what I have but another argument is expected an d I tried a byte value but it still did not work

Comment: I was able to figure out on MainActivity5 what to fix. It does not crash anymore but I am not able to navigate to the other activity on the app. Would sending data constantly via bluetooth to app cause this issue?

Comment: Yes because you start the MainActiviy5 multiple times inside the loop for

Comment: That makes sense so then how would I be able to transmit the data continuously? I know I need a loop to continually send data but should start MainActivity5 once.

Comment: why not send the whole list at once ?

Comment: So I did send a whole list but I am not able navigate in the app. I got rid of the for loop and the intent lines are underneath the run() loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230554/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-romko-smuk).

Comment: Use a broadcast receiver to send data to the activity